# Python list will print but not return

Tags: python, list, return, nonetype

I am working on code that takes a csv file then returns a list of datapoints for every line in the csv file. The lists will be sorted by date and by location.

The code makes the list how i want it, but does not return the list when called.

The first function reads the file and makes data points. the second function  calls the first, sorts and (hopefully) returns the data

```
def CreateDataStructure(data):
allData=[]
with open(data,'r') as data:

    dataRead=data.readlines()
    for line in dataRead[1:]:
        splitList=line.split(",")
        dataPoint =[splitList[25],splitList[1],{splitList[19]:splitList[9]}]
        allData.append(dataPoint)
sortedData=sorted(allData)
return sortedData


def compileData(filename,counter,sortedData):    
    if counter==0:
        sortedData=CreateDataStructure(filename)
        compileData(filename,1,sortedData)
    else:
        if counter<len(sortedData):

            if sortedData[0][0]==sortedData[1][0] and sortedData[0][1]==sortedData[1][1]:#change these back
                compDict=dict(list(sortedData[0][2].items())+list(sortedData[1][2].items()))
                sortedData[0]=[sortedData[0][0],sortedData[0][1],compDict]    
                sortedData.pop(1)
                compileData(filename,counter,sortedData)
                counter=counter+1
            else:
                sortedData+=[sortedData.pop(0)]
                counter=counter+1
                compileData(filename,counter,sortedData)
        else:
           from itertools import groupby
            for key, locationGroup in groupby(sortedData, lambda x: x[0]):
                bigList=[]
                smallList=[]
                    for date in locationGroup:
                    smallList.append(date)
                    bigList.append(smallList)
            print bigList
            return bigList

print compileData("fakeData.csv",0,[])
```

When I run this code, it prints what I want (biglist, which I pasted below in case you are wondering) but returns None (noneType object). **Why do returning and printing give two different things, and how can I fix this**?

`[[['744701', '40974', {'Alkalinity': '234'}], ['744701', '41018', {'Alkalinity': '252'}], ['744701', '41058', {'Alkalinity': '270.53'}]], [['744701', '40974', {'Alkalinity': '234'}], ['744701', '41018', {'Alkalinity': '252'}], ['744701', '41058', {'Alkalinity': '270.53'}]], [['744701', '40974', {'Alkalinity': '234'}], ['744701', '41018', {'Alkalinity': '252'}], ['744701', '41058', {'Alkalinity': '270.53'}]]]`

Comment: You are using only one return statement in that code (`compileData()`). Your if statements have no return value in some cases.

Comment: I'd guess you'd also want to swap the lines `bigList=[]` and `for key, locationGroup...`.
Also, what you probably need is a return in front of every call to `compileData`.
And last but not least: Please check the code-formatting before posting.

Comment: I would offer a recommendation for using `pandas` to do this kind of stuff, `pandas.read_csv` will read in the csv file and you can do `groupby`s quite easily - I'm not entirely sure what the mapping from csv to desired output list is though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `compileData` function has multiple branches of execution, meaning it can return at multiple points. However, only *one* of them (`counter !=0 and counter >= len(sortedData)` i.e. the last `else` branch ever returns anything.

For example:

```
if counter==0:
    sortedData=CreateDataStructure(filename)
    compileData(filename,1,sortedData)
```

even if the that `compileData` call manages to reach the last `else` branch, i.e. the one that prints and returns your result, nothing is actually done with the result. That means that after `compileData(filename,1,sortedData)` finishes, the data it returns is discarded and function execution continues until it eventually reaches the end and implicitly returns `None`.

This should fix *that* problem:

```
def compileData(filename,counter,sortedData):    
    if counter==0:
        sortedData=CreateDataStructure(filename)
        return compileData(filename,1,sortedData)
    else:
        if counter<len(sortedData):

            if sortedData[0][0]==sortedData[1][0] and sortedData[0][1]==sortedData[1][1]:#change these back
                compDict=dict(list(sortedData[0][2].items())+list(sortedData[1][2].items()))
                sortedData[0]=[sortedData[0][0],sortedData[0][1],compDict]    
                sortedData.pop(1)
                counter=counter+1
                return compileData(filename,counter,sortedData)
            else:
                sortedData+=[sortedData.pop(0)]
                counter=counter+1
                return compileData(filename,counter,sortedData)
        else:
           from itertools import groupby
            for key, locationGroup in groupby(sortedData, lambda x: x[0]):
                bigList=[]
                smallList=[]
                    for date in locationGroup:
                    smallList.append(date)
                    bigList.append(smallList)
            print bigList
            return bigList
```

## Update

You could make your function (subjectively) a bit easier to understand by [returning early](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#returning-values) instead of nesting several `ifs`. Your function would then look like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
...
def compileData(filename,counter,sortedData):
    if counter==0:
        sortedData=CreateDataStructure(filename)
        return compileData(filename,1,sortedData)

    if counter<len(sortedData):
        if sortedData[0][0]==sortedData[1][0] and sortedData[0][1]==sortedData[1][1]:#change these back
            compDict=dict(list(sortedData[0][2].items())+list(sortedData[1][2].items()))
            sortedData[0]=[sortedData[0][0],sortedData[0][1],compDict]    
            sortedData.pop(1)
            counter=counter+1
            return compileData(filename,counter,sortedData)

        sortedData+=[sortedData.pop(0)]
        counter=counter+1
        return compileData(filename,counter,sortedData)

    for key, locationGroup in groupby(sortedData, lambda x: x[0]):
        bigList=[]
        smallList=[]
            for date in locationGroup:
            smallList.append(date)
            bigList.append(smallList)

    print bigList
    return bigList
```

Comment: do you see any other problems?